# Print class objects with specific variable value in common

Tags: c++, class, object

If you called three objects in main from the same class like so:

```
customer one(856756, "New York");
customer two(896557, "New York");
customer three(896571, "Washington");
```

How would you be able to print a list of those who have the same city in common when you have a class like this:

```
class customer {
public:
    customer(int RegNr, string City) { this->RegNr = RegNr; this->City = City; }
    customer(){}
    ~customer() { cout << "Customer with registration number " << RegNr << " has been destroyed." << endl; }
    void setRegNr(int RegNr){this->RegNr=RegNr;}
    void setCity(int City) { this->City; }
    string getCity() const { return City; }
    int getRegNr() const { return RegNr; }
private:
    int RegNr;
    string City;
};
```

Comment: comparing the `getCity()` output from each of your instances

Comment: @ignacio 
If I compare customer one and two it will only check those two.
How can I compare them "dynamically" so that every new object that's created get compared?

Comment: To compare them dynamically you'll have to create an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your `setCity` is wrong, it doesn't ask for a `string` and it doesn't set anything. Using some mem intialization lists and some best practices we get:

```
class Customer 
{
public:
    Customer (int regNr, string city) : city(city), regNr(negNr) {}
    Customer(){}
    ~Customer() { cout << "Customer with registration number " << regNr << " has been destroyed." << endl; }

    void setRegNr (int nr) { regNr = nr;}
    void setCity(string city) { this->city = city; }
    string getCity() const { return city; }
    int getRegNr() const { return regNr; }
private:
    int regNr;
    string city;
};
```

Now when you have 3 objects:

```
Customer one(856756, "New York");
Customer two(896557, "New York");
Customer three(896571, "Washington");
```

To iterate these it's better to put them into an array instead:

```
std::array<Customer, 3> customers = {one, two, three};
```

Now we can loop over the elements and print out if the cities are the same:

```
for(int i = 0; i < customers.size(); ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < customers.size(); ++j)
  {
    if(j == i)
      continue;

    if(customers[i].getCity() == customers[j].getCity())
    {
      std::cout << "City with regnr " << customers[i].getRegNr() << " and " << customers[j].getRegNr() << " have the same city.\n";
    }
  }
}
```

There are some functions you can use in `<algorithm>` to speed this up / have less code for the same thing but writing out the loops makes it easier to understand.